# Migration Symfony 1.2.1 -> 1.4.11

Tags: symfony1, migrate

At what should I need to be careful when I migrate a project made in with Symfony 1.2.1 to Symfony 1.4.11 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should follow the instructions here: http://www.symfony-project.org/tutorial/1_4/en/upgrade

There is a validator which you can run on your code that will tell you which files have code that needs to be changed. Also, remember since you want to go from 1.2.1 -> 1.4.11, you will first need to upgrade to 1.3. So you would run:

$ php symfony project:upgrade1.3

and then switch to 1.4.